# display html content only once after user signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the **devise** gem to authenticate users in my RoR app. I added some logic to it. For example only displaying some links or content if the user is signed in, like so `<% if user_signed_in? %>` and then some content... ending with `<% end %>`

Now, what I would like to do is display content (example a `div` with a paragraph in it) only the first session--the first time a user signs into my website.

Any tips in how i can implement that kind of logic in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tiago Farias` is correct with this - this will be a job for the `sign_in_count` attribute is to indicate how many times a `user` has signed in:

[image]

I've tried doing something similar before with `Kirti Thorat`, but we found there was a problem with the number of times `Devise` stores the `sign_in_count` - something like it started from `0` or something

--

Anyway, not to intrude on `Tiago Farias'` answer, you'll basically just need to do this:

```
<% if user_signed_in && current_user.sign_in_count == "1" %>
    HTML here!
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh come on @Cyzanfar ! Besides, this logic should be in a controller, not in a view.

Comment: Yeah you should really give `Tiago Farias` the accepted answer - he was first & did give the info. However, I would disagree that it "should be in the controller" - if he wants to show a single `div`, you'll have to put conditional logic in the view

Answer (score 1):

Devise has a module called [Trackable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable) which contains this logic of counting sign_in of an user for you. From the doc:

> sign_in_count - Increased every time a sign in is made (by form,
>   openid, oauth)

Just add the Trackable module in your model and then in your code:

```
if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
  welcome_path
else
  #do something else
end
```

Comment: I remember there's something that won't work with this - Devise does something strange with the sign_in_count; I've forgotten what it is exactly, it's something like having the files you need

Comment: It was just that you must do "== 1" instead of "== 0".

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the first time ever the user logs into your website you can add a field within the  user model (table), e.g. bool seen.
If you are only referring to the current session, you can store information within the user session.
Either way, if you want to provide a new div the first time the user logs in, just check the value of the new field (seen) and display or hide the html.

UPDATED
Create a migration

```
class AddRoleToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    add_column :users, :already_seen, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

the above code will add a new column to the user table with false as default value

The first time that the user will log in the value of already_seen will be false.
If already_Seen is false you will display the html element otherwise you will not.

After display your div element you must change the value of already_seen to true, e.g.

```
user.already_seen = true
user.save()
```

When the user will log after the first time you won't display your div element because the value of already_see is equal to true.

Comment: I am talking about the first time ever the user logs in. Could you be more specific about te field I need to add in my user model?